# Gridview should display dropdownlist "Text" which is selected instead of "Value"

Tags: c#

I have a Form where in I have two DropdownList "Status" & "Shelf" both have SQL Datasources and they are dependent. When ever I Insert a record, it enters perfectly but the "Status" & "Shelf" columns contain "Values" instead of "Text".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you set parameters using `SelectedValue` property, you get the `DataValueField` bounded to droupdown list. if you need to get `DataTextField`, then try as below

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", DdlStatus.SelectedItem.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shelf", DdlShelf.SelectedItem.Text);
```